# Change zoom with html tag event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'am a beginner in GMaps API and javascript, so this should be an easy question for you that are really experts. I have started to "play around" with the API, and wanted to try a simple thing, but I couldn't make it! I have look around for the answer, but I didn't get it. I have created the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

    //CREATE THE MAP
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-35.8190,-61.9010),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    //GET THE ZOOM
    var ez = map.getZoom();

    //TRYING TO CHANGE ZOOM FROM EXTERNAL LINK (DOESN'T WORK)
function cambiarZOOM(nro) {
    var newZ = ez + nro;
    map.setZoom(newZ);
    }

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Now, the HTML:

```
<html><body onload="initialize()">
<input type="button" onclick="cambiarZOOM(5)" value="CAMBIAR ZOOM">
</body></html>
```

Well, now I'am reading about google.maps.trigger(); but I'm not getting it. I will apreciate  a lot your answer!. THANK YOU!

Comment: Try using GMAP3 its easy in it. http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/. If your cambiarZOOM function is running on click put if(map) then use google.maps.event.trigger(map, "option");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cambiarZOOM function is local to the initialize function (it is contained by that function).  It needs to be in the global scope (outside of any function declaration) to be used in an HTML event handler (like "onclick").  Your "map" variable also needs to be global to be used in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
function initialize() {

    //CREATE THE MAP
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-35.8190,-61.9010),
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function cambiarZOOM(nro) {
    //GET THE ZOOM
    var ez = map.getZoom();
    var newZ = ez + nro;
    map.setZoom(newZ);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Well, first of all, thanks to everyone of you! I tryied to correct the code myself, but it seems to be very sensitive to the position of ALL statements.. after trying I just copied and pasted this last code, and it worked fine! I guess the detail I was missing was the position of .addDomListener. When I put it at the bottom, the code didn't work, but putting it where it is now, fixed it. An advise to begginers, be careful of the position of statements! THANKS TO ALL

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a local variable to `initialise()` - the other functions don't have access to it, so declare it outside of `initialise()`. Then have a new function that returns the map's current zoom.

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-35.8190,-61.9010),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function getCurentZoom() {
  return map.getZoom();
}

function cambiarZOOM(nro) {
  var newZ = getCurentZoom() + nro;
  map.setZoom(newZ);
}    

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `cambiarZOOM` function and `map` variable are only accessible within the scope of the initialize function.  To use a function on an onclick event, either it has to be available globally (this is discouraged), or you have to attach the function to the button while the function is in scope.

If you give your button an id (`id='zoomButton'`), you can attach `cambiarZOOM` within the initialize function like so:

```
...
function cambiarZOOM(nro) {
    var newZ = ez + nro;
    map.setZoom(newZ);
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('zoomButton');
button.onclick = function () { cambiarZOOM(5); };
```